# Facebook and Google+ login with Dart

Tags: facebook, dart, google-plus

I would like to write a website using Dart as scripting language.
However, I need a robust way to login my users using their Facebook and/or Google+ ids.
So, I would like to know what is the best way to implement Facebook and Google+ login with Dart in a Website?﻿

Please, if is it possible, I would like to have code snippets to better illustrate the process.

Comment: Do you want to do the login on the client or server side?
Have you done some research yet? How far did you come, what didn't work.
'Give me some code' questions are usually considered inappropriate on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 4):

There is a pub package available for Google OAuth 2 login http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_oauth2_client

and one that claims to support facebook http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/simple_oauth2_server